# How to Retrieve data from two table by arranging dates from both table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables 
1.Trans_Credit
[image: Trans_Credit]

2.Trans_Debit
[image]

I want to show record like

```
Record of 252688
Date       Transaction        Reason          Credit_Amount  Debit_Amount
8/17/2016  (From)Thowheed     Purcase return  2500
8/24/2019  (From)Mohamed      Balance Money   1000
08/11/2016 (To)Thowheed       purchase                       2500
8/20/2016  (To)Mohamed        Salary                         3000
8/14/2016  (To)Thowheed       Expanse                        5000
```

as well as i want to arrange date by desc
     I am using asp.net and sql server

Comment: Why not have one transaction table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restructure the tables. Why you need 2 table? Use a single table with a "transaction_type" field. e.g. value D for debit, C for credit OR -1 for Debit, 1 for Credit.

In you current structure this record will appear twice :

```
Mohamed        Salary                         3000
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use Union to merge result from two table. After that, u use Order by with date column

Comment: Select date, credit as debit from transaction_credit union all select date, debit as money from transaction_debit